# How to use multiple MySQL rows and values in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Product table and I want to get back the name, price , and image of all products. However, nothing is showing up(blank). The connection is not the problem, I have checked. Also when I try try to (print $result;) to check what is going on, it gives me the error (Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string).

Code:

```
<?php
            require_once('mysqli_connect.php');

            $sql = "select name, price, image from Product where stars>3";

            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result){
                print $result;
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo '<section class="products">';
                    echo '<div class="product-card">';
                    echo '<div class="product-image"><img src="' . $row['image'] .'"></div>';
                    echo '<div class="product-info">';
                    echo '<h4>' . $row['name'] . '</h4>';
                    echo '<h5>' . $row['price'] . '</h5>';
                    echo '</div></div></section>';
                }
            } else {
                echo "Couldn't issue db query";
                echo mysqli_error($conn);
            }

            // Close connection
            mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: First do a `print_r($result);` and see what you get as output.

Comment: Do not use procedural mysqli with object oriented together. FAILURES will occur.

Comment: "Do not use procedural mysqli with object oriented together. FAILURES will occur" No it's possible to mix procedural mysqli with object oriented mysqli without failures @IncredibleHat  "It is possible to switch between styles at any time. Mixing both styles is not recommended for code clarity and coding style reasons. " source http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php

Comment: Failures will still occur due to confusing the methods and not crossing them over properly. My statement stands. Only the really experienced should attempt mixing, and if someone is experienced, they wouldn't in the first place. So its a moot point. "*Just don't do it*" ;)

Comment: Don't get me wrong i fully support "Do not use procedural mysqli with object oriented together." @IncredibleHat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` to `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()`

Try this:

```
<?php
    require_once('mysqli_connect.php');

    $sql = "select name, price, image from Product where stars>3";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result){
        print_r($result);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<section class="products">';
            echo '<div class="product-card">';
            echo '<div class="product-image"><img src="' . $row['image'] .'"></div>';
            echo '<div class="product-info">';
            echo '<h4>' . $row['name'] . '</h4>';
            echo '<h5>' . $row['price'] . '</h5>';
            echo '</div></div></section>';
        }
    } else {
        echo "Couldn't issue db query";
        echo mysqli_error($conn);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```